# Maintain value in text field even though record is changed in Ext JS 6

Tags: extjs, textfield

I am working on Ext JS 6. I have grid with multiple records and a separate comment panel in which I have a text box, when I select a record and type something in textfield in comment panel and change the record that textfield of comment panel should be blank but once again I go back to previous record then I should be able to see the comment which I wrote in text field

I am sharing the code:

```
Ext.define('iram.result.comments.main.view.NewCommentPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'newCommentPanel',

    requires: [
        'Ext.button.Button',
        'Ext.form.field.Text',
        'Ext.form.field.TextArea',
        'Ext.layout.container.HBox',
        'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager'
    ],

    init: function () {
        Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
    },

    margin: 10,

    maxHeight: 100,

    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'restrictedtextarea',
        reference: 'newCommentTextarea',
        maxHeight: 100,
        flex: 1,
        publishes: ['value'],
        bind: {
            value: '{newCommentText}',
            disabled: '{!changeContextIdForCommentsPanel}'
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        hidden: true,
        allowBlank: false,
        bind: {
            value: '{newCommentText}'
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        margin: '0 0 0 10',
        iconCls: 'iwp-icon-gen_comment',
        scale: 'large',
        formBind: true,
        listeners: {
            click: 'createNewComment'
        },
        localized: {
            tooltip: 'comments.main.addComment'
        }
    }]

});
```

Comment: Have a look at this example http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#binding-selection

Comment: Do you have any part of the code ready? Can you share a fiddle? The code you share above doesn't contain any info about the textfield handling and how it's supposed to bind to the grid selection and sync  the values.